# Wood texture on merge mesh geometry

Tags: merge, three.js, mesh, texture-mapping

I want to have several geometries merged together and then apply a texture to make it look like a real piece of wood.

Is it possible? Here what I got for result:

[image: Wood]

Here's what I tried:

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'Escaliers 3D/1-3-2-5-Bois.jpg' );
var mesh = [], no = 0;
var meshes = [];
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 2, 10, 1 );
mesh[no] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry );
meshes.push(mesh[no]);
no++;

geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0.5, 0.5, 10, 32 );
mesh[no] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry );
mesh[no].position.set( 1, 0, 0 );
mesh[no].rotation.x = 0;
mesh[no].rotation.y = Math.PI/2;
mesh[no].rotation.z = 0;
meshes.push(mesh[no]);
no++;

geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 5, 10, 1 );
mesh[no] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry );
mesh[no].position.set( -3.5, 0, 0 );
meshes.push(mesh[no]);
no++;
geometry = mergeMeshes(meshes);

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

scene.add( mesh );

function mergeMeshes (meshes) {
    var combined = new THREE.Geometry();
    for (var i = 0; i < meshes.length; i++) {
        meshes[i].updateMatrix();
        combined.merge(meshes[i].geometry, meshes[i].matrix);
    }
    return combined;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly the image represent the result you have from the above code, right ?

Comment: Yes, but it need to be more unify like a real wood stair.

Comment: _unify like a real wood stair._ What do you mean ? You want all the meshes in one object ?

Comment: Yes, one object. Without the restart of the texture image.

Comment: Post all your code, by the way I don't know what `mergeMeshes` does. Create a [complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I find difficult to understand what you mean by _restart of the texture image_. From what I see, you are not using the `TextureLoader` correctly.

Comment: I'll post my complete small code. I know that there is a chance that I use the texture before it's loaded (will add 'OnLoad' code later). This mesh is 3 objects merged together. The texture is restarting on each object instead of doing it one on all objects together (look closely on the image).

Comment: Can't post all codes, it won't let me??? I added the missing function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging the two meshes used to create this was the answer.